# Auto update for win from application remote host file type

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, auto-update

In click once application when application check for update from remote location as specified in [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1zyc39fb.aspx). What should i host on remote site example like www.download.com\testapplication dll, exe or any thing else. Do i need to change "will user install from network share or website or dvd" during publish for remote host. Lots of question asked about auto update but not explained how to host remote for update, might be possible i am dumb to get hidden answer.

Answer (score 1):

Im using click-once as deploymentmethod for an Application.
The Application is hostet in our Intranet. (Link refers on *.application)

Each time when im publishing a new Release of my Application, VisualStudio generates/manipulates the Folderstructure automatically.

In my publishing root, there are one Folder and two files

- Application Files
- setup.exe
- XX.application

The folderstructure contains ALL releases of the past and the actual one.

My Settings are

- Application is only online availiable
- NO! Special options, basically the Optionspage is blank

Im just increasing the Versionnumber. Thats how the depoying works for me.

If a user clicks on the link (.application), the newest release is synced to his PC and then executed.

Unfortunately i'm using a german version of VisualStudio, so im quite sure, Screenshots wont help you a lot.

Comment: what if application is like skype installed on someone pc and will be updated if there is any update.

Comment: Short answer is yes. As long as the executiontarget is the .application file